# text alignment with "=" sign

Tags: html, css, alignment, text-alignment

I want to align the text with "=" sign, as of the picture below:

[image]

I can do it using mathjax but I want to make it using css if possible. But the way I did it is not making the equals to sign aligned one to another. I want your help.

This is what I tried,

```html
Solution, <br>
Given, f(x) = 3x <br>
g(x) = x + 2 <br>
fog(x) = 18 <br>
To find: x = ?, <br>
Now, <br>
fog(x) = 18 <br>
or, f(x + 2) = 18 <br> 
or, 3(x + 2) = 18 <br>
or, x + 2 = 6 <br>
&therefore; x = 4
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to relatively align text with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52087925/how-to-relatively-align-text-with-css)

Comment: @Aziz NO, I've already said I can do it using mathjax, but I want to make it using css.
The answer to that question is using mathjax

Answer (score 1):

You can use display, text-align and width in your classes:

```css
.c-left{
  text-align: right;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.c-mid{
  text-align: center;
  width: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.c-right{
  text-align: left;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="c-left">a + b</div>
  <div class="c-mid">=</div>
  <div class="c-right">c</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="c-left">2a + 2b</div>
  <div class="c-mid">=</div>
  <div class="c-right">3c</div>
</div>
```

Not sure if this is what you need...

Comment: Another way is to use a old-school 'table'

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is arranging the text into a form that's easily style-able using CSS.
Assuming your text comes in the form of a JSON array of strings, i.e:

```
[
  "Solution,",
  "Given, f(x) = 3x",
  "g(x) = x + 2",
  "fog(x) = 18",
  "To find: x = ?,",
  "Now,",
  "fog(x) = 18",
  "or, f(x + 2) = 18",
  "or, 3(x + 2) = 18",
  "or, x + 2 = 6",
  "&therefore; x = 4"
]
```

...you want a function which turns it into style-able markup.

Here's an example using vanilla Javascript and CSS grid:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('math-element')].forEach(el => {
  // reset, in case you run this more than once...
  el.innerHTML = '';
  
  // we need JSON.parse as dataset.text is a string
  JSON.parse(el.dataset.text).forEach(text => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    // split each row by `=` sign, if it has any
    text.split('=').forEach(t => {
      const span = document.createElement('span');
      if (text.split('=').length < 2) {
        // adds `.single` to items which are single on their row
        span.classList.add('single');
      }
      span.innerHTML = t;
      el.appendChild(span);
    });
    // add a `<hr>` after each element
    const separator = document.createElement('hr')
    el.appendChild(separator);
  })
})
```

```css
math-element {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}
math-element hr {
  display: none;
}
math-element span {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 2px 0 1rem;
}
math-element span:not(.single) {
  font-style: italic;
}
math-element span.single {
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: .5rem;
  font-style: normal;
}
math-element span + span {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 2px;
}
math-element span + span:before {
  content: '=';
}
```

```html
<math-element data-text='["Solution,","Given, f(x) = 3x","g(x) = x + 2","fog(x) = 18","To find: x = ?,","Now,","fog(x) = 18","or, f(x + 2) = 18","or, 3(x + 2) = 18","or, x + 2 = 6","&therefore; x = 4"]'></math-element>
```

You don't have to inline the value as a string, as I did, you can simply create the element(s) on the fly and run the `forEach` directly on the data instead.

If you find CSS grid syntax and logic confusing, you can always create a `<table>` with `<tr>` and `<td>`s, which will give you simpler selectors. Out of principle, I advise against it.

I used `<hr>`s to mark the end of each "row" (CSS grid requires all cells to be siblings). Instead, you could just nest the row contents into a single element (`<div>` ?) and hard-code the column widths.

Obviously, the CSS is yours to modify (i.e: remove `font-style`'s, adjust the `padding` values, etc...).

A final note: if one "row" contains more than one `=` sign, because of this rule:

```
math-element span + span {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}
```

spans 2 and 3 in a row (and subsequent, until end of row) will be displayed one below each other, each prefixed with a `=` sign and aligned with the rest (which is not that bad, IMHO). If you want to change this behavior, you probably want to provide a

```
math-element span + span + span {
  grid-column-start: 3;
}
```

... rule, and so on. Also you'll need to change `grid-template-columns` to match:

```
math-element {
  grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr;
}
```

...matching the number of "columns".